# Can an apparently intractable integral be made tractable in this way?

Tags: calculus, integration

Say there are two integrals:
$$F(\beta)=\int_{b_0}^{\beta}f(b)\: db$$

$$H(\rho)=\int_{r_0}^{\rho}h(r)\: dr$$

where $F(\beta)$ is (apparently) intractable while $H(\rho)$ is tractable (expressible in elementary functions).

And we know that $b$ is a function of $r$ and that
$$f(b(r))=h(r)$$

Can this info be used to make $F(\beta)$ expressible in terms of elementary functions?  How?

Comment: If you take tractable to mean "expressible in elementary functions" then no since $F(\beta)$ is intractable. I imagine this is not quite what you have in mind however. It is true that substitutions of this sort can make a difficult looking integral easy. As far as I know this can be a bit of of magic trick.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
$h(r) = e^r$ has elementary integral
$$
\int e^r\;dr
$$
and $f(b) = e^{e^b}$ has non-elementary integral
$$
\int e^{e^b} db
$$
despite the fact that $b(r) = \log r$ gives us $f(b(r))=h(r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Each elementary function is differentiable, and its derivative is again an elementary function. $H$ is elementary means therefore, also $h$ is elementary.

Because $h$ is elementary and $f\circ b=h$, also $f\circ b$ is elementary.

$\ $

$$F(\beta)=\int_{b_0}^{\beta}f(b)db$$

Use that $b$ is a function of $r$: change the integration variable:

$$b_0=b(r_0),\ \beta=b(r_1),\ \frac{db(r)}{dr}=b'(r)\ \curvearrowright\ db=b'(r)dr$$

$$F(r_1)=\int_{r_0}^{r_1}f(b(r))b'(r)dr$$

Use that $f(b(r))=h(r)$: Restrict $f$ to domains $D_i$ where the restriction $f_i=f|_{D_i}$ is bijective, and consider each $f_i$. The $f_i^{-1}$ are the partial (compositional) inverses of $f$.

$$f_i(b(r))=h(r),\ \curvearrowright\ b(r)=f_i^{-1}(h(r))$$

$$F(r_1)=\int_{r_0}^{r_1}f(f_i^{-1}(h(r)))b'(r)dr$$

$$F(r_1)=\int_{r_0}^{r_1}h(r)b'(r)dr$$

Even if the integrand of $F$ is elmentary, $F$ can be an elementary integral or a non-elementary integral.

Take e.g. the example of GEdgar's answer.